# Printing white images in PowerPoint handouts

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating lecture slides on a dark background. An example slide is below:
[image]
Here's how the handout from this slide looks:
[image]

Any suggestions as to how to avoid losing the image? Do I simply have to avoid using white images?

Update: A colleague has suggested using yellow images. This is an improvement, but still produces handouts that are hard to see:

[image]
[image]

The reason for using yellow or white on blue is to maximise contrast in the lectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a powerpoint generated background (your image is 100% white), then that would explain this. Try using images that have the background included, or create a generic background image you can use on each page, placing the content above. Then it should export both your background and content in the handouts.

Ideally though, in the interests of saving ink, you should be keeping your slide backgrounds mostly white. Maybe use a colored header and/or footer image to spruce it up a bit.

Comment: Slide backgrounds are removed when printed (to save ink), but this is the source of the problem with regards to printing. I'm trying to avoid 'blocky' images by adding transparency.

Comment: I assumed that was the case. Unfortunately white+transparent images will never print well on white paper, which is why I suggested creating a background image or even better, always having a light colored background with dark text in your slides.

Comment: Thanks very much. It looks as though this is a dead-end; I'd hoped there'd be a feature that would mean all-white images would be detected as such by PowerPoint and automatically inverted when printed. Maybe that's a lot to expect though! Never mind. Your offering is the best solution - simply don't use them!

Answer (score 0):

On the `View` tab, under `Color/Grayscale`, select `Black and White` mode. This provides new options for the picture's context menu (<kbd>Right mouse click</kbd>), one of which is `Black and White Setting...`. Under `Black and White Setting...`, select the option `Inverse Grayscale`.

Now, you can return to color view (`BLACK AND WHITE` tab), and under print settings, select `Pure Black and White` instead of `Color`. Your picture will print inverted, and you can save on color ink.